# "Remember me" doesn't call after_sign_in_path_for when starting user session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using `after_sign_in_path_for` method to instantiate a user's session variables when they log in. However, this is bypassed when the user is logged in via the "Remember me" functionality. Is there another function that is called when a user's session is started here? How can I ensure that a user's session is setup the same as sign_in as for "remember me" automatic sign in?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything quite as straightforward.  I think there are at least a couple of options.

You could have a `before_filter` in your `ApplicationController` that checks if there's a user signed in and if so, whether you have done whatever you want to do to set up their session, something like this:

```
before_filter :set_up_session_if_needed

protected

def set_up_session_if_needed
  if user_signed_in? && !session[:is_set_up]
     # set up session variables here, followed by:
     session[:is_set_up] = true
  end
end
```

The first request after a user is signed in (either via a 'real' sign-in or rememberable) will cause your session variables to be set up and then the `:is_set_up` flag will be stored in the session so it won't be done again on subsequent requests.  Note that `set_up_session_if_needed` should then be the method called during your `after_sign_in_path_for` so that you're DRY and the `:is_set_up` session variable is dealt with properly.

Another thing to consider is if you want any other stuff to happen at this point - for example, are you using `:trackable` and do you want any of those fields updated?  In that case, you could add a `sign_in(user, :force => true)`, but then you'd want to make sure that *wasn't* called when they'd actually just signed in rather than been remembered, otherwise your `:trackable` sign-in count would be wrong.  If you don't need to worry about this, you wouldn't need slightly different handling depending on sign-in vs. rememberable, so you could just not call `set_up_session_if_needed` at all from `after_sign_in_path_for` because the above code will be called as a before_filter on wherever you redirect to anyway.

This general approach feels a little icky but should do the job I think.  Otherwise you'd probably need to try overriding part of devise's Devise::Strategies::Rememberable strategy which is what tries to retrieve the user given a rememberable cookie (which might be tricky - I haven't tried this), or replace the strategy altogether if that's even possible. There are probably even ickier possibilities, but I won't try to describe them.  The before_filter is probably the simplest approach!

Comment: Yeh that ought to work, it never occurred to me to do it that way. So simple. Thanks